# Display Path on Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

for some reason the path in the button below will not display. I have added the Path and a TextBlock so you can see that there is data, here is the button:

```
<Button DataContext="{Binding RegisterCommandButton}"
                        Command="{Binding Send}"
                        Tag="{Binding CommandDisplay}">
    <!--Style="{StaticResource BtnSmBlue}"-->
    <StackPanel>
        <Path Data="{Binding IconGeometry}" Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Black" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IconGeometry}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

This is the data the button binds to:

```
public CommandVM RegisterCommandButton { get; set; } = 
    new CommandVM { CommandDisplay = "Register",
        IconGeometry = App.Current.Resources["refresh1"] as Geometry,
        Message = new CommandMessage { Command = CommandType.Insert } };
```

As you can see, there is data:
[image]

**Edit:**

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="refresh1" Figures="M433.109 23.694c-3.614-3.612-7.898-5.424-12.848-5.424c-4.948 0-9.226 1.812-12.847 5.424l-37.113 36.835             c-20.365-19.226-43.684-34.123-69.948-44.684C274.091 5.283 247.056 0.003 219.266 0.003c-52.344 0-98.022 15.843-137.042 47.536             C43.203 79.228 17.509 120.574 5.137 171.587v1.997c0 2.474 0.903 4.617 2.712 6.423c1.809 1.809 3.949 2.712 6.423 2.712h56.814             c4.189 0 7.042-2.19 8.566-6.565c7.993-19.032 13.035-30.166 15.131-33.403c13.322-21.698 31.023-38.734 53.103-51.106             c22.082-12.371 45.873-18.559 71.376-18.559c38.261 0 71.473 13.039 99.645 39.115l-39.406 39.397             c-3.607 3.617-5.421 7.902-5.421 12.851c0 4.948 1.813 9.231 5.421 12.847c3.621 3.617 7.905 5.424 12.854 5.424h127.906             c4.949 0 9.233-1.807 12.848-5.424c3.613-3.616 5.42-7.898 5.42-12.847V36.542C438.529 31.593 436.733 27.312 433.109 23.694zM422.253 255.813h-54.816c-4.188 0-7.043 2.187-8.562 6.566c-7.99 19.034-13.038 30.163-15.129 33.4             c-13.326 21.693-31.028 38.735-53.102 51.106c-22.083 12.375-45.874 18.556-71.378 18.556c-18.461 0-36.259-3.423-53.387-10.273             c-17.13-6.858-32.454-16.567-45.966-29.13l39.115-39.112c3.615-3.613 5.424-7.901 5.424-12.847c0-4.948-1.809-9.236-5.424-12.847             c-3.617-3.62-7.898-5.431-12.847-5.431H18.274c-4.952 0-9.235 1.811-12.851 5.431C1.807 264.844 0 269.132 0 274.08v127.907             c0 4.945 1.807 9.232 5.424 12.847c3.619 3.61 7.902 5.428 12.851 5.428c4.948 0 9.229-1.817 12.847-5.428l36.829-36.833             c20.367 19.41 43.542 34.355 69.523 44.823c25.981 10.472 52.866 15.701 80.653 15.701c52.155 0 97.643-15.845 136.471-47.534             c38.828-31.688 64.333-73.042 76.52-124.05c0.191-0.38 0.281-1.047 0.281-1.995c0-2.478-0.907-4.612-2.715-6.427 C426.874 256.72 424.731 255.813 422.253 255.813z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
```

Comment: What's the XAML for `refresh1`?

Comment: @MarkFeldman Added it

Answer (score 0):

Damn it! Stupid mistake, for other people, ensure you set the Stretch property!